# Drive D missing on heavy load

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive

I have an ASUS laptop running Windows 10 with two disk drive (1 @ 500GB SSD and 1 @ 1TB HDD). The Windows OS is installed on C drive (SSD), while games and personal data are installed and stored in D drive (HDD).

A few weeks ago, I realized the drive reading process suddenly slowed down when I browse my files in Windows Explorer, and recently, my D drive would suddenly unreadable (totally missing) under these condition:

1. Playing games. Suddenly the game stopped completely, and when I checked on Windows Explorer, the D drive is not there.
2. File transfer. I tried to backup my files in case of hardware failure. When the file copying is still in progress, suddenly an error appeared, indicating that the files I tried to copy is no longer there.
3. Anything that cause a heavy load on D drive.

Every time I restarted my laptop, the D drive will appear again, however it goes undetected again under the conditions I described above. For additional notes:

- The latest "Cumulative Updates for Windows" is installed on 14 July 2021.
- Windows is updated regularly, yet it never cause any problems on my laptop.
- Regarding the hardware condition, this laptop is about 3 years old, and I never encountered any hardware failure.

What I have done:

1. Tried to check for disk error using CHKDSK command on Command Prompt, but no bad sector detected.
2. Rescan drives on Disk Management, yet the D drive still won't appear.
3. Checked on Device Manager, and the hard drive is not detected on Disk drive tab.

Full specs:

- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz 2.21 GHz
- RAM: 32 GB
- VGA: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080
- Windows: Windows 10 Home Single Language, version: 20H2

I'm literally going crazy here since I also need this laptop for work purpose, and it's difficult to get hardware support on local stores in my area under extended lockdown situation. If possible, I wanted to look for any software related solutions before coming to hardware failure conclusion.

EDIT:
[Screenshot from Speccy - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tVYk.jpg)

[Screenshot from Speccy - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HaDP.jpg)

Comment: Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1666445/edit) into your post the SMART data of the disk (a screenshot will do). If you don't have a program that can do so, use for example [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy), Storage section. As caution, ensure that all data on D is well backed-up.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have edited the post and added some screenshots from Speccy

Comment: When you run this command what does it say `wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi PATH MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus get /format:List`. To send the data to the clipboard `wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi PATH MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus get /format:List | clip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your disk may be dying - save your data and replace it.

The SMART data shows a high
[Reallocated Sectors Count](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9105)
value of 1,744.

This parameter is defined as:

> Reallocated Sectors Count S.M.A.R.T. parameter indicates the count of reallocated sectors (512 bytes). When the hard drive finds a read/write/verification error, it marks this sector as "reallocated" and transfers data to a special reserved area (spare area).
>
> This is a critical parameter. Degradation of this parameter may indicate imminent drive failure. Urgent data backup and hardware replacement is recommended.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, it's a little difficult to find a replacement under current condition (COVID and all), so do you have any suggestions to kinda "slow down" the dying disk process aside from high usage?

Comment: You could try to reformat the disk with slow format (meaning not quick), which will of course destroy all data. But even if there is an improvement, don't trust this disk to keep its data, so always have backups.

Comment: BTW, why I can't find SMART data on my SSD? What if I needed to find out whether my SSD is also dying or not?

Comment: If it's older, it might not support SMART. SMART was once not available for all SSDs. A modern SSD is sure to support it.